# sum of complex numbers less or equal than 1

Tags: complex-analysis

Question:

So let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and assume that $z_1,\ldots, z_n$ are complex numbers such that
\begin{align}
|\sum_{j=1}^n z_jw_j|\leq 1
\end{align} 
for all $w_1,\ldots,w_n \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\sum_{j=1}^n |w_j|^2\leq 1$. Show that $\sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|^2\leq 1$. Show that the reverse also holds.

So for the reverse I think that you have to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
Which states that for an inner product space we have that $|\langle w, z \rangle | \leq  ||z||\cdot||w||$, but I can't find how to apply it. For the other direction of the proof I have literally no idea.

Comment: Let $w_i = 1/\sqrt{n}$ and then apply C-S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, choose $$w_j=\frac{\bar{z_j}}{(\sum{|z_j|^2})^{1/2}}$$

For the second part, check the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

For the first part, choose $$w_j=\frac{\bar{z_j}}{(\sum{|z_j|^2})^{1/2}}$$

For the second part, check the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

EDIT:

We want to slow that if $\sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|^2\leq 1$, then given any $w_1,\ldots,w_n \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\sum_{j=1}^n |w_j|^2\leq 1$, we have $ |\sum_{j=1}^n z_jw_j|\leq 1$

By the inequality, $|\sum z_j w_j|^2\leq (\sum|z_j^2|)(\sum|\bar{w_j}^2|)$
$\leq (\sum|z_j^2|)(\sum|w_j^2|)$

Then $|\sum z_j w_j|^2\leq (\sum|z_j^2|)(\sum|w_j^2|)$
$\leq 1 \times 1 =1$.
Then since $|\sum z_j w_j|^2\leq 1$ and $|\sum z_j w_j|$ is real, we have $|\sum z_j w_j| \leq 1$
Then

Comment: The link states that

Comment: The link states it for $|\sum_{j=1}^n z_j\bar{w}_j|$, but I have to proof it for $|\sum_{j=1}^n z_jw_j|$ How can I still apply it ?

Comment: @TheTriforce I want to use https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/1/0/210d6c97e4c166bc4100adf9148ae9f0.png .

Comment: But how I then prove that $|\sum_{j=1}^n z_jw_j| \leq 1 $

Comment: @TheTriforce I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, That helped me a lot